# Do we have to declare all properties in constructor?

Tags: php, oop

I am new to OOP. Do we have to declare all the properties in constructor?
For example:

```
  private $_conn;
  private $_limit;
  private $_page;
  private $_query;
  private $_total;

public function __construct($conn, $query){

$this->_conn = $conn;
$this->_query = $query;

$rs = $this->_conn->prepare($this->_query);
$rs->execute();
$this->_total = $rs->rowCount();
}

public function getData($page = 1, $limit = 10){

$this->_limit = $limit;
$this->_page  = $page;

if ($this->_limit == 'all'){
    $query = $this->_query;
} else {
    $query = $this->_query." LIMIT ".(($this->_page - 1) * $this->_limit).", $this->_limit";
}
$rs = $this->_conn->prepare($query);
$rs-> execute();

while ($row = $rs->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    $results[] = $row;
}
```

I got this from somewhere on internet. The coder didn't declare $_limit and $_page properties in constructor. Is that for not to create the properties if we don't use the getData method? and can we use this logic for other programming languages like Java, C#, C++?

Comment: No. You only need to assign in the constructor the variables that need a non-evaluated value to begin with. If the default value is a simple string/number/array, you can set it in the declaration (which is not in the constructor), or it can be left as null.

Comment: whether you declare a property in the constructor depends on whether the object needs to know a value for it immediately when the object is created, or whether populating it can be left until later. It's totally dependent on the purpose of the property. There's no rule about it. You'll find plenty of objects with multiple properties whose constructors accept no arguments at all.  And yes that same basic concept will apply to most OO languages. P.S. if the properties are public you can of course set them directly, without using a constructor or a method.

Comment: Is this the full code ? How do you plan to use this ? The `while ($row = $rs->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))` is a bit strange (completely useless....) as `::fetchAll()` return all the results. Also, no, unless you try to use type in your code, in which case I would recommend using nullable such as `__construct(?\PDO $conn = null, ?string $query = null) :?array` and check every time if your params are null or not

Comment: This is not full code just part of it. I just wondered why constructor doesn't have all the properties, thanks all of you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

every method/function (including constructor of the object) should declare only the variables it's going to use.

Answer (score 1):

It is not necessary to declare all the members in the constructor. you may even leave it blank

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to declare all the members in the constructor, it is not necessary but it is also not bad practise to declare them. It is up to you. Both approach are fine.